# The callback from $.ajax is triggering next in Jquery Queue without it being called

Tags: ajax, jquery, get, queue

Okay, So example $node.queue(function1).queue(function2).queue(function3);

Function 1 is calling an

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: callback,
    dataType: "script",
    // cache: true
});
```

As a callback for function1 it is running a function inside the file it just got.  The file it retrieves has the NEXT function instead it.  However, what it is doing is triggering the next as it calls the function instead of the file it just retrieved.   Function2 then errors because the function has not run before it.  If you run the queue again after guaranteeing that the file has loaded it works fine. Is there anyway to ensure that callback will not trigger next until the appropriate time.

The callback function looks like.

```
Apps['apps'].start( next ); // I have tried it without next inside it as well.
```

Comment: Are you calling .dequeue() anywhere? Can you post all of your code?